# Getting image path one by one in multiple file upload

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a multiple file upload working fine but there´s one thing that I want to do before save the image path in my database. My database have five columns to save different images, I want to get the image path one by one in different variables if necessary to save in different columns that´s in my database.

Column 1 = Image 1
Column 2 = Image 2
....

Here´s the code:

xhtml page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{siteBean.fileUploadAction}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

ManagedBean

```
public void fileUploadAction(FileUploadEvent event) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStream in = event.getFile().getInputstream();

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        FacesContext aFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext) aFacesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();

        String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");

        File folder = new File(realPath + "/img/sites/");
        folder.mkdirs();

        String  file = realPath + "/img/sites/" + event.getFile().getFileName();
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) 
        {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush(); 
    } 
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I´m using Netbeans 7.4, primefaces 4.0, common io 2.4, common file upload 1.3 and jsf 2.2.

Comment: `new File(file).getAbsolutePath()` doesn't work?

Comment: hi Hannes this´s not what i´m looking for, my problem is the file variable, because i´m using multiple file upload if I upload to file for example the file variable will have the two file:
    file variable = file 1
    file variable = file 2
What I want  is a way to have this file in two variable:
    file variable 1 = file 1
    file variable 2 = file 2